# Add column in r with the preview values in another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 2 columns. Patient_Id and time (when visit the doctor).
I would like to add a new column "timestart" which have 0 at the first row for each different Patient_id and the other rows with the same id have the preview value from column time.
I think to do this with loop for, but I am new user in R and I don’t know how.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To select all-but-last values from a "vector" -say `x  = 1:4`-, you can use `x[-length(x)]` so something like `cbind(x, c(NA, x[-length(x)]))` shows `x` and its previous value. To perform operations by group see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega). You could, also, add a more  [specific example with the expected output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: sorry it’s my mistake. Your answer is very useful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group by 'Patient_id' and create the new column with the `lag` of 'time'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Patient_id) %>%
   mutate(timestart = lag(time, default = 0))
#    Patient_id  time timestart
#        <int> <int>  <int>
#1          1     1      0
#2          1     2      1
#3          1     3      2
#4          2     1      0
#5          2     2      1
#6          2     3      2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Patient_id = rep(1:2, each = 3), time = 1:3)
```